# "Unspecified error" when using external SD as root for KSWEB web server

Tags: external-sd

After installing KSWEB web server on an Android tablet, everything worked fine out of the box.

The problem started when I realized I needed the web server root to be in an external SD card as there was not enough free space left in the internal storage. By default, the host configuration file points `docroot` to `/storage/emulated/0/htdocs` (port 8000); this is somewhere in the internal storage and works perfectly.

The path of the folder I want to use as the website root is `/storage/826C-1AEF/htdocs` (I got this address from the folder's properties); however, when I point the Apache server to this location, it finds it but I get an "unspecified error" which prevents the Apache service from starting.

I understand `emulated/0` is some kind of link effectively pointing at the `htdocs` folder, located in internal storage; there is obviously an error in the way I specify the new path to external storage; is there a different "emulate" for external storage, for it certainly didn't like the direct path?

Can anyone see my mistake?

Comment: KSWeb bases on apache, which is a native application. As far as I know on unrooted devices an external card is only accessible using the Android Java API, not via standard C file API.